# Android: canvas drawing, drawARGB and drawColor

Tags: android, canvas, live-wallpaper, ondraw

small question:

i made a live wallpaper with a runnable i made.
Why when i try to .drawARGB or .drawColor with the color white or any color, on a canvas, it shows for a split second and turns back to the color black all over the screen?

but when i draw lines with .drawLine they do stay there as if have been printed in?

Comment: Would you plz share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable hardware acceleration using

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
```